# Optimize query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
results = Report.where(:car => 'xxxx').group(:date, :name, :car).select('date, name ,car, info, MAX(price) AS max_price')
for customer in customers
  result = results.where(:date => customer.date, :name => customer.name, :car => customer.car).first
 .... rest of the code ....
end
```

I have a database with many records ~20,000, so **I want to optimize the code** and cache results in memory.
Once again: my overall intention is make this code more efficient in terms of time. I want it to run faster than it is now and I want to reduce amount of database calls.

I am thinking of making my inital `results` object an array. I have a remote database so each `.where` query takes sometime. When I make `results` an array by adding `.to_a` - I load it to memory. So I think, it should be better(but not really sure)

Something like:

```
results = Report.where(:car => 'xxxx').group(:date, :name, :car)
                .select('date, name ,car, info, MAX(price) AS max_price')
                .to_a

for customer in customers
 result = results.select {|result| result.date == customer.date and result.name == customer.name and result.car == customer.car }
                 .first
end
```

Comment: "Will this work" seems like an odd question. Have you tried it? BTW your methodology does not do a whole lot it simply overwrites a local variable (`result`)  n times (where n is the number of customers). So result is equivalent to the result of the last customer only. Please explain what your overall intention is because I do not think optimization is your issue here

Comment: @engineersmnky updated

Comment: Why can't you have customer_id in reports table which makes it easier for you to fetch all reports for given customers?

Comment: @Surya because I have a certain database structure which is not written by me and this structure might be not so good but I can't modify it.

Comment: My statement about your methodology still stands and I still implore you to *"Please explain what your overall intention is because I do not think optimization is your issue here"*

Comment: @engineersmnky okay. Look. My overall intention is make this code more efficient in terms of time. I want it to run faster than it is now. And my guess(only guess) that I can rmake it faster by converting activerecord relation to array.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the best things to have an association to fetch all reports for customers. In the case when you can not do so, I would recommend making only one query instead of n+1(as stated in the question) like this:

```
results = Report.where(:car => 'xxxx').group(:date, :name, :car)
                .select('date, name ,car, info, MAX(price) AS max_price')
                .where(:date => customers.map(&:date), :name => customers.map(&:name), :car => customers.map(&:car))
```

Assuming customers is an array of objects which respond to `:name`, `:car`, and `:date` methods.

One thing that should be noted is it does not guarantee that it will fetch reports of an exact customer. For that, you'd have to verify it by iterating through the `results` object yourself.

Comment: So how do I rewrite this line: `result = results.where(:date => customer.date, :name => customer.name, :car => customer.car).first`  with your code?

Comment: Just like in the last line on second block of code mentioned in your question: `customers.each do |customer| result = results.detect{ |result| result.date == customer.date and result.name == customer.name and result.car == customer.car }`

Comment: Okay, right now as understand my code makes `n` calls to database. Where `n` is number of customers. Will modified code as you suggested make just one call?

Comment: Yes, except now you that in Ruby as there's no way to pinpoint exact customer's report in reports table. It will also limit the call to include only possible dataset instead of fetching all reports.

Comment: How did you find that  with this line:  `.where(:date => customers.map(&:date), :name => customers.map(&:name), :car => customers.map(&:car))` code makes just one call to database?